# Binding object values from radio input with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-value

I have a json file

```
$scope.favoriteThings = [
    {nr: 1, text: "Raindrops on roses"},
    {nr: 2, text: "Whiskers on kittens"},
    {nr: 3, text: "Bright copper kettles"},
    {nr: 4, text: "Warm woolen mittens"},
    {nr: 5, text: "Brown paper packages tied up with strings"},
    {nr: 6, text: "Cream colored ponies"},
    {nr: 7, text: "Crisp apple streudels"},
    {nr: 8, text: "Doorbells"},
    {nr: 9, text: "Sleigh bells"},
    {nr: 10, text: "Schnitzel with noodles"},
    {nr: 11, text: "Wild geese that fly with the moon on their wings"},
    {nr: 12, text: "Girls in white dresses with blue satin sashes"},
    {nr: 13, text: "Snowflakes that stay on my nose and eyelashes"},
    {nr: 14, text: "Silver white winters that melt into springs"}
  ];
```

-I am using **ng-repeat** directive to repeat the above array.

```
<li ng-repeat="thing in favoriteThings">
        <input type="radio" value="{{thing}}" ng-model="$parent.selected" name="stuff"/>
          {{thing.text}}
      </li>
```

- I am displaying the value obtained by selecting a checkbox as 
`Selected thing: {{selected}}{{selected.nr}}`

- then i get the following output

`Selected thing: {"nr":5,"text":"Brown paper packages tied up with strings"}`
To acces the **"nr"** attribute i try to use `{{selected.nr}}` but that does not work
Any ideas why? 
**[PLUNKER LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/3xCZckY85COEkanLm29y?p=preview)**
**EDIT: I also want to access the TEXT attribute**

Answer (score 1):

Just edit your html body to be like that

```
      <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="thing in favoriteThings">
            <input type="radio" value="{{thing.nr}}" ng-model="$parent.selected" name="stuff"/>
              {{thing.text}}
          </li>
        </ul>
        <hr/>
        Selected thing: {{selected}}  {{getText(selected)}}
      </body>
```

And add this function to your controllers

```
      $scope.getText  = function(_nr){
          var found = $filter('filter')($scope.favoriteThings, {nr: _nr}, true);
          return found[0].text
        }
```

you can see it working here [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kFN2C2hOgeYKeOagfqlz?p=preview)

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear.. i want to acces the text attribute also

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `value` attribute with the `ng-value` directive:

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ul>
     <li ng-repeat="thing in favoriteThings">
        <!-- REPLACE interpolated value
        <input type="radio" value="{{thing}}" ng-model="$parent.selected" name="stuff"/>
        -- with the ng-value directive -->
        <input type="radio" ng-value="thing" ng-model="$parent.selected" name="stuff"/>
          {{thing.text}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <hr/>
    Selected thing: {{selected}}<br>
    Number: {{selected.nr}}<br>
    Text:   {{selected.text}}
  </body>
```

By using interpolation, `value={{thing}}`, the `thing` object was getting converted to a string. The `ng-value` directive preserves the `thing` object as an object.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/GNCwrOlck7BJgYBcvxsb?p=preview)